# When memory is swapped to disk, and later RAM is freed, does the memory get swapped back into RAM?

Tags: memory, swap, esxi, pagefile

I'm guessing the answer depends on the OS. In this case, it is VMware ESXi. I created a low memory condition by migrating several VM's to a host that has memory over-committed. Once page sharing and ballooning kick in, there is plenty of RAM without having any paged, however, these processes take time. During this time, ESXi swaps memory to disk.

So, I am left with a condition that I end up with plenty of free host memory, but yet a significant amount has been swapped to disk.

When will this memory be swapped back in to RAM? Only once it is accessed? And this also means, when it is accessed, there will be delay? Is this avoidable?

Answer (score 2):

Only when it's accessed. All modern virtual memory OSs are "demand paged", meaning that things are paged in as a result of page faults, which happen when "invalid" pages are referenced.

(An "invalid" page is simply one that will raise a page fault when referenced. It might actually be in RAM, in a page cache. The name comes from the "valid" bit in the x86/x64 page table entry. Another name for this is "resident", but this name is a little misleading, as again, an "invalid" page may in fact be in RAM, in a page cache.)

This is somewhat modified by prefetching and readahead and so on, but fundamentally, things are still demand-paged.

The reason for this is that when a program has been idle for a while (and is "swapped to disk", its memory access pattern the next time it does something will not necessarily be similar to what it was previously. So it would be somewhat simplistic to just page in what was in memory before.